# Application chat Client Server - cant send the second message

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, chat

I'm writing a Client-Server chat application. I can connect them and I can send-receive the first message. But I can't send the second one. I tried to add the do...while() statement for a repetition but It doesn't work. Could some one help me to resolve this problem? Many thanks
This is my server class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4999);
        Socket serverSocket = server.accept();
        
        System.out.println("client is connected");

        String messIn = "", messOut = "";

        InputStreamReader serverInput = new InputStreamReader(serverSocket.getInputStream());
        
        BufferedReader serverBufIn = new BufferedReader(serverInput);

        Scanner serverScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        PrintWriter serverWriter = new PrintWriter(serverSocket.getOutputStream());

        do {
            messIn = serverBufIn.readLine();
            System.out.println("client : " + messIn);
            messOut = serverScanner.nextLine();
            serverWriter.print(messOut);
            serverWriter.flush();

        } while (messOut.equals("quit"));

        serverSocket.close();
        serverWriter.close();
    }
}`

This my client class

`import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 4999);
        System.out.println("You are connected. Say something!");

        String messIn = "", messOut = "";

        InputStreamReader clientInput = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader clientBufIn = new BufferedReader(clientInput);

        Scanner clientScanner = new Scanner(System.in);     

        PrintWriter clientWriter = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        
        do {
            messOut = clientScanner.nextLine();
            clientWriter.println(messOut);
            clientWriter.flush();

            messIn = clientBufIn.readLine();
            System.out.println("server : " + messIn);

        } while (messOut.equals("quit"));
        
        clientSocket.close();
        clientWriter.close();
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

try `while (true) { }`

my code:

```
public static void newSocket(int port) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (run) {
            try {
                final Socket socket = ss.accept();
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            while (true) {
                                int i = socket.getInputStream().available();
                                if (i > 0) {
                                    byte[] bytes = new byte[i];
                                    socket.getInputStream().read(bytes, 0, i);
                                    String s = new String(bytes);
                                    String[] split = s.split("\\|");

                                    if (split.length > 1) {
                                        if (split[0].equals("hello")) {
                                            String msg = split[1];
                                            System.out.println(msg);
                                            PrintStream p = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                                            p.println("hello back");
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ss.close();
    }
```

Comment: Hi 4zzzz, thank you for your answer. But may I'm waiting another simple thing.